# How to add certain prefixes to lines from a file

Tags: c, while-loop, feof

So I have a text file (called So.txt) that has in it:

```
Will
Happy
12.50
2012
Kanye
Wolves
15.99
2016
```

I'm writing a program that reads from it and adds a certain prefix to each read line. Basically I would like the output to look like this:

```
Name of singer: Will
Name of song: Happy
Price: 12.50
Year of release:2012
Name of singer: Kanye
Name of song: Wolves
Price: 15.99
Year of release:2016
```

This is the program.

```
song_file = fopen("So.txt", "r");
char singleline[150];
while (!feof(song_file) ) {
                fgets(singleline, 150, song_file);
                puts(singleline);
                printf("Name of singer: ");
                printf("Name of song:           ");
                printf("Price:                  ");
                printf("Year of release:        "); 
                
            }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your target is output like the below code.

Maybe you can have a look, and we can discuss it later on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRLEN 10

char Prefix_word[][20]={
    "Name of singer :",
    "Name of song : ",
    "Price : ",
    "Year of release : "
};

void main(void){
    FILE *fd;
    fpos_t Current_pos;
    fpos_t Start_pos;

    char singleline[STRLEN];
    int index=0;
    int len=0;

    fd = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    /* Get the Start position */
    fgetpos(fd, &Start_pos);

    /* Initial string array */
    memset(singleline, ' ', STRLEN);

    while(!feof(fd)){
        /* Counting the lenght of string */
        len++;

        /* Read 1 character to check whether to go to the next column*/
        fread(singleline, sizeof(char), 1, fd);

        if(singleline[0]=='\n'){
            fgetpos(fd, &Current_pos);
            fsetpos(fd, &Start_pos);
            fread(singleline, sizeof(char), len, fd);

            /* Print */
            printf("%s %s\n",Prefix_word[index++], singleline); 

            /* Get Start position */
            fgetpos(fd, &Start_pos);

            /* Initial */
            len=0;
            memset(singleline, ' ', STRLEN);

            if(index>=4){
                printf("================\n");
                index=0;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fd);
}
```